# Тестовое задание, с чего нужно начать?

Tags: javascript, mysql, проектирование, php7

Подскажите в общих чертах как это должно выглядеть на выходе:

> Есть некий вебсайт на котором показывается баннерная реклама с частотой показов до 200шт в минуту.
>   Каждый показ баннера порождает ajax запрос к серверу для сохранения статистики, и возвращает в браузер id сохраненного показа.
>   Время ответа от сервера не должно превышать 1 секунду.
>   При этом паралельно с сохранением статистика на сервере должен уходить запрос в бэк систему, ответ на который занимает 10-15 секунд.
>   Необходимо реализовать механизм создания очереди и отправки запросов в бэк систему с сохранением результата оправки в таблицу статистики на сервере.
>   Задержка между показом баннера и сохранением информации на бэк системе не должна превышать 5 минут.

Стек: php7 + mysql + js.

С чего начать ?

Comment: спасибо за коррекцию)

Comment: А сколько параллельных запросов обработает бакэнд ? Если не много - у вас проблема, очередь к бакэнду будет бесконечно расти и превысит 5 минут ... потому как скорость роста очереди 200 в минуту должна покрываться скоростью суммарной обработки параллельных запросов бакэндом

Comment: количество запросов не уточняется, думаю им можно принебречь

Comment: Если вы описали все технологии которые хотите использовать и не собираетесь подключать всякие системы кеширования в оперативной памяти, то при приходе запроса пишите в БД статистику, возвращаете id, у записи ставится статус "новый". набор фоновых процессов (или один многопоточный) постоянно берет очередную новую запись (выборку в работу конкретным обработчиком распаралелить например остатком от деления id на число процессов, что бы не делать блокировки) отсылает на бакэнд, дожидается результата, пишет результат   в ту же таблицу, заодно    меняя статус на "обработано"

Comment: Спасибо за ваш ответ, вопрос больше не актуален.